# how to read parquet file(large size 1 GB) from the azure blob storage without downloading in local machine

Tags: python, pandas, azure, dask, parquet

from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="ABC", blob="/xylem/pr/folder_with_parquet_files")

Comment: Have you tried anything, like reading the dask documentation about remote file access? https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/remote-data-services.html

Comment: I don't want read from the local (folder) I want to  read parquet from the azure blob storage

Comment: Did you read that doc, which explicitly mentions azure?

Comment: yes, not find any solution, help appreciated!

Comment: What did you try? What went wrong? Please read this site's documentation n how to ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Below is the python code which I did a repro to read parquet file from Azure blob storage:

```
import logging
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as py
import azure.functions as func
from io import BytesIO
from azure.storage import blob
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__

def main():
    CONN_STR = "STORAGE_CONNECION_STRING"
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(CONN_STR)
    # MAP SOURCE FILE
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="parquetfiles", blob="userdata1.parquet")
    content =  blob_client.download_blob()
    stream = BytesIO()
    content.readinto(stream)
    processed_df = pd.read_parquet(stream, engine='pyarrow')
    print(processed_df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Have a look on the below test output screenshot from my local VS-Code:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ki4j.png)